# Contextual search point to search center site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search-results

SharePoint 2013 - I don't see an option where I can point "Search this site" to enterprise search center. is it possible that when user selects "Search this site" it will point to search center (http://search2013.col.it) instead of out of the box _layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx page.

I like to keep the drop down for search available and no matter what user select it will point to search center to display results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured search setting at site level (/_layouts/15/enhancedSearch.aspx?level=site) and added "Configure Search Navigation" links and now it's working the way I needed to. Also added a link "This Site" and url is http://search2013.col.it/Pages/results.aspx?u=http://inside.col.it/sites/sales

By the way,I have noticed I am not receiving reply or successful solution thru this site. Is this site still active?

Comment: Yep this site is still active...or so I think. People just ignore the questions they don't find interesting / they don't know / they'd not like to answer. And most of the high rep experts seem to have gone on a sabbatical or are too busy to be spending their time here ;). So you'd have to either wait for a person who knows about search ( Matthew McDermott is the most active user here for the search tag ) to answer your question or solve it yourself which you seem to have done. :)